# Does the grandparent process of a child process becomes its parent if its parent ends

Tags: process, fork

Suppose I have at the following program

```
 for(i=0; i<3; i++)
 pid = fork();
```

My understanding is that 8 processes will be created once the for loop iterates.
[image: Processess]

Now suppose the Highlighted Process gets terminated, will the **First Parent Process**, end up becoming the parent of the other 2 processes and the **Grandparent** of the **Last Process** in the chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a process does not become the parent of its children's children or their descendents.

After a parent process terminates, children of that deceased parent immediately become children of a specific system-designated process.

Traditionally that system-designated process was a single, system-wide process known as `init`.  One of that process's responsibilities was to "reap" (collect the exit status of) orphaned processes when they eventually terminate.  Traditionally that `init` process had a process ID equal to 1.

However, over the last few years it has become common to have multiple `init` processes in addition to, or perhaps instead of, the original PID=1 `init`.  For instance, the processes running in a container or in a user login session might be given their own dedicated `init` process.  So on a modern system it's possible for your orphaned child processes to end up with a parent PID that is not 1.

The answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177361/18253 goes into much more detail on this.